# Redirect Powershell Errors

Tags: powershell

I have a script which will audit NTFS permissions.

```
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = Get-ACL $Folder.FullName | % { $_.Access  }
    ForEach ($ACL in $ACLs){
        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.FileSystemRights + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $outputCSV
    }
}
```

However because the script runs as the context of the user, there are certain folders the account doesn't have access to so spits our errors in the powershell CLI saying access denied etc. How can I:

```
a). Hide it from the Powershell CLI
b). Redirect it to a notepad/txt file log so I still have the information.


+ $Folders = dir $pathToFolders -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (F:\SEPM:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ACL : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

It does not write this to the text file using the below method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect the error stream, use the `2> filename` syntax (or `2>> filename` to append).

To demonstrate, let's use this function:

```
Function Test {
    Write-Error "Written to stderr"
    Write-Output "Written to stdout"
}
```

Then you could make the call `Test 2> stderr.log` to write "Written to stderr" to the file stderr.log. You can still redirect stdout as well, `Test 2> stderr.log > stdout.log` would write "Written to stderr" to stderr.log, and "Written to stdout" to stdout.log.

**EDIT:**
When doing this within a pipeline, make sure to do the redirection in the part of the pipeline that writes to error. That is,

`$Folders = dir $pathToFolders -recurse 2> stderr.log | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}`,

not

`$Folders = dir $pathToFolders -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} 2> stderr.log`

Note that this means you could actually redirect errors from different commands to different error logs, if you wish, `$Folders = dir $pathToFolders -recurse 2> dir.err | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} 2> where.err`

Comment: + $Folders = dir $pathToFolders -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (F:\SEPM:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
Get-ACL : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. For example: it does not write this error to the file?

Comment: Hm, where did you put the redirection? You need to place it so it redirects the command which actually generates the error, not after the entire command. I'll edit in the proper call in the answer.